# MongoDB Query to lookup in three documents with name users, collections, products,

Tags: mongodb, sorting, lookup

I have three collections with name users, collections, and products.

**Users**: - id, username, email

**collections**:- id, user_id, name, image

**products**:- id,collection_id, image, price

I want to write a query to fetch users with the sum of all collections and in each collection total sum of products and sort record according to the field

```
allCollectionsProductsCount
```

. I highly appreciate your assistance.

Output should be like:

```
[

{ userId:1,

name:"abc",

email:"abc@xyz.com",

allUserCollectionsTotal:5,

collectionproducts:[

    {collectionId:1,totalProducts:20},

    {collectionId:2,totalProducts:40}
    ],

allCollectionsProductsCount:60

}

]
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.